# Why the performance is affected with a LEFT JOIN and a GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, database-performance

I'm not understanding what MySQL (InnoDB) is doing with my queries. I have a query to extract data from two tables and it runs in ~35 ms. If I run the query without the LEFT JOIN, it does it in ~2.5 ms. Even the “equivalent” query to what the LEFT JOIN is doing takes ~0.5 ms. Why?

The “slow” query is the following:

```
SELECT
    `Assigned`.`id`,
    `Assigned`.`name`,
    (COUNT(`Action`.`id`)) AS `Action__total_actions`

FROM `actions` AS `Action`

LEFT JOIN `users` AS `Assigned` ON (`Assigned`.`id` = `Action`.`user_assigned_id`)

WHERE
    `Action`.`company_id` = 1 AND
    `Action`.`action_date` BETWEEN '2014-12-28 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-28 23:59:59'

GROUP BY `Action`.`user_assigned_id`
ORDER BY `Assigned`.`name` ASC;
```

And I have one primary index for the table **users** and the next index for table **actions**:

```
ALTER TABLE `actions` ADD INDEX `actions_report_by_assigned` (`company_id`, `action_date`, `user_assigned_id`);
```

This is when it gets weird. If I “extract” the LEFT JOIN, the index is still working (for both queries), but the next one is 10 times faster:

```
SELECT
    `Action`.`user_assigned_id`,
    (COUNT(`Action`.`id`)) AS `Action__total_actions`

FROM `actions` AS `Action`
WHERE
    `Action`.`company_id` = 1 AND
    `Action`.`action_date` BETWEEN '2014-12-28 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-28 23:59:59'

GROUP BY `Action`.`user_assigned_id`
ORDER BY `Action`.`user_assigned_id`;
```

I think the index is well designed because both queries go through the same total rows that are counting. The EXPLAIN command tells me that the Index it's being used, but it also says in the extra column this: “*Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort*” in both queries (besides, one is 10 times faster).

Maybe is the filesort with my LEFT JOIN, because if I remove the GROUP from my first query, it speed up until ~15 ms. Sadly, I can't do that. Am I missing something?

Should I ignore this? What is the best way to solve it?

Comment: It would be nice to know why the down vote. o_ó

Comment: Some people just have to many reputation points to spend on down-voting.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the *order* that the tables are being accessed.

The `LEFT JOIN` is an **outer join**, it has to return rows from the table on the left side that don't have a matching row from the table on the right side.

An `INNER JOIN` only returns rows that are matching, so MySQL only has to find matching rows, so it can use either table as the driver for the nested loops operation, and usually, MySQL will use the table that returns fewer rows.

With the **outer join**, MySQL can't use the table on the right side as the driver, because there may be rows from the table on the left side that also need to be returned.

That's the **why** of it. As to how to solve it...

It's bit odd to have an expression in a `GROUP BY` clause, and not return that expression. (It's valid to do that in SQL, but how does the client know which row is for which value of the `GROUP BY` expressions?)

What is the purpose of the `GROUP BY Action.user_assigned_id`?

If the `LEFT JOIN` query you are talking about (which we don't see in the question) is the same as the `INNER JOIN`, just replacing the `INNER` keyword with the `LEFT` keyword...

With a `GROUP BY col`, sometimes MySQL can make efficient use of an index with leading column `col` to avoid a "Using filesort" operation, but in your case, there's an `ORDER BY` on a different expression, so I don't think there's any way to get around a "Using filesort" operation.

Your best bet is probably making sure you have an appropriate index to satisfy the predicates in the WHERE clause, if that limits the rows to a small subset of rows in the table.

```
... ON `actions` (`company_id`, `action_date`, `user_assigned_id`, `id`)
```

MySQL should be able to make use of that index for the equality predicate on `company_id`, and for a range scan operation on `action_date`. Having the other two columns in the index makes that a covering index, so the query can be satisfied entirely from the index, without any lookups to data pages in the underlying table.

If that's the case, the Extra column in the EXPLAIN output will show "Using index".

Comment: I was trying with an INNER JOIN (which is more correct) and forgot it. I edited the question and leave it as LEFT and avoid confusion. Either way, doesn't matter which one I use, the execution time is the same. The purpose of `Action.user_assigned_id` is to group by user, I think (and it looks like) it's the same as grouping by `Assigned.id`.

I just tried to change the order of columns in the INDEX and get rid of the ORDER clause as you suggested, but time increased at ~50 ms.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an INDEX on the single column `user_assigned_id` because multiple columns indexes are only usable when the query is done on all of the columns of the index OR on the first columns only, in the order of the index so reordering you index to this might also work:

```
ALTER TABLE `actions` ADD INDEX `actions_report_by_assigned` (`user_assigned_id`, `company_id`, `action_date`);
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html:

> For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).

For now, your `actions_report_by_assigned` INDEX can't be used for this JOIN:

```
INNER JOIN `users` AS `Assigned` ON (`Assigned`.`id` = `Action`.`user_assigned_id`)
```

Because `user_assigned_id` is the last column of your multiple columns index.

Comment: I just tried to change the order of columns in the INDEX, but time increased at ~50 ms and the INNER JOIN is using its own PRIMARY INDEX from the table users. If I run the two queries in different requests, I can get the same data (in two different sets) in ~4 ms (tho, I don't know what could happen when my db gets bigger if I do that).

Comment: And did you try to define an INDEX on `user_assigned_id` alone? I agree you already have the PRIMARY INDEX on your `users` table for the `users` side on the JOIN but not for the `actions` side of it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use left join on big tables.
Hint : Split the query in smaller piece.
5 minutes query will execute less than 1 seconds
Try it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Also check the explain plan.
Get the fields involved in the join.
Check whether, applied index on both side on the joining fields.
And again check the explain plan, you can see the count get reduced.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).